# Flutter Firestore Query Field in Object

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a Flutter app and am trying to add documents to a list, where the contractorUserId value field (under jobBids) in Firestore is equal to the logged-in user. The image below shows the structure of my Firestore structure (contractorUserId in jobBids)
[Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayART.png)

I'm using the following code:

```
_jobsCollectionReference.snapshots().listen((jobBidsSnapshot) {
      if (jobBidsSnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        var jobsWithBids = jobBidsSnapshot.docs
            .map((jobBidsSnapshot) =>
                JobWithBids.fromMap(jobBidsSnapshot.data(), jobBidsSnapshot.id))
            .where((mappedItem) => mappedItem.jobBids != null)
            .where((mappedItem) =>
                mappedItem.jobBids
                    .map((e) => e.contractorUserId == loggedInUser.uid)
                    .toList()
                    .length >
                0)
            .toList();
```

This code results in a list with all objects where the contractorUserId field exists. However, the intention was to only add the documents where the contractorUserId is equal to the Logged in user.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because the piece of code below evaluates to `true` since you're just checking the length of the list even if `e.contractorUserId == loggedInUser.uid` equals false :

```dart
 mappedItem.jobBids
   .map((e) => e.contractorUserId == loggedInUser.uid)
   .toList()
   .length >
   0
```

So your code is actually:

```dart
var jobsWithBids = jobBidsSnapshot.docs
  .map((jobBidsSnapshot) =>JobWithBids.fromMap(jobBidsSnapshot.data(), jobBidsSnapshot.id))
  .where((mappedItem) => mappedItem.jobBids != null)
  .where((mappedItem) => true) //This is what it evaluates to
  .toList();
```

You should switch `map` to `where` in the last check, so it filters any list that does not satisfy the condition. See below:

```dart
var jobsWithBids = jobBidsSnapshot.docs
  .map((jobBidsSnapshot) =>JobWithBids.fromMap(jobBidsSnapshot.data(), jobBidsSnapshot.id))
  .where((mappedItem) => mappedItem.jobBids != null)
  .where((mappedItem) => mappedItem.jobBids
      .where((e) => e.contractorUserId == loggedInUser.uid)
      .toList()
      .length > 0
  ) 
  .toList();
```